# What's the difference between persistent objects and linq-to-sql?

Tags: linq-to-sql, persistence

My manager as work keeps talking about persistent objects.  I'm more familiar with linq-to-sql.  What is the differences between them and what is an example of persistent objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I frequently use DevExpress XPO persistent objects. The biggest difference for me is that I don't have to have an existing database, or even know what the target database platform will be, while I'm creating my classes.

DevExpress has a lot of details on their site.  Look for XPO ([eXpress Persistent Objects](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/ORM/)).

Comment: thanks, thats a nice site.  are there other products like this?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, your boss is referring to persistent objects as being POCO style classes (abstracting the database functionality from your entities). In the strictest definition I would say that LINQ to SQL objects are persistent objects, but they are not POCO classes. You can't take those classes and switch to a different back end platform with them.

Comment: There are portions of this statement that, given present day technology, are no longer true. Specifically, L2S has been superceded by EF, as of EF4 a Code-First approach is now possible (whereby you start your development with the definition of POCOs, rather than a DB/Schema), and your POCOs do not necessarily require decorators (as there are metadata attributes which can be used to instruct EF to use a separate, sometimes non-public, type for schema/annotation data.) This allows us to use the same POCOs across multiple 'incompatible' persistence solutions, be it EF/MSSQL or sth like db4o.